# Changing code snippet in a .class file

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

I have a jar file that contains a class file that I need to change a host name in.  Simple change if I can get the code decompiled correctly.

When I tried extracting and decompiling with jd gui then recompiling with javac, I get compilation errors because I believe the decompiler didn't read the code correctly.

Next I tried to open the .class file in notepad++ and just change the host name amidst all the symbols and other things, then rejar, and that didn't work either.

I know this is similar to a lot of questions on here, but I can't seem to find my answer.

Comment: Can't you change it in the source-code and rebuild?

Comment: ASM a byte code manipulation lib is  a good bet: can read .class, alter it and write it.

Comment: @Shark the class is pretty complex, and I honestly am not familiar with everything it is doing, so I don't want to change any code to fix the comp errors.

Comment: If you have access to the source code, then just change it in there and recompile. What you're attempting to do here is quite frankly insane and supremely problematic. A lot more hassle than just correcting the source code, recompiling and rebuilding. If it's just a host name, then it should be simple to find in the source and amend it. Shouldn't be hardcoded in source, of course, but that's another matter. Which you could easily fix via a properties file.

Comment: @ManoDestra maybe I am misunderstanding your response, but the issue is that I don't have the correct source code.  I only have the decompiled code from the jar file, which seems incorrect.  I also don't know what the class does or how to test it if I were to change the source code after decompilation

Comment: I usually follow these step to patch a .jar file:
1. Use jd to decompile.
2. Copy source file that I want to change to a eclipse project.
3. Add original .jar to project classpath.
4. Rebuild project.
5. Copy .class file from /bin folder to extracted .jar file.
6. Rejar.
Not sure if you add original .jar to classpath to javac. Hope this method help.

Comment: The class is so complex that instead of changing it's sourcecode, you decided to decompile it, change something, and hope it recompiles back... ? You do realize you're probably going to have to change it slightly just so it builds again, right?

Comment: You implied above that you had access to the source code. `@Shark the class is pretty complex, and I honestly am not familiar with everything it is doing, so I don't want to change any code to fix the comp errors.`. Therefore, if you do have access to the source, then change that and rebuild. Otherwise, you should not be touching the binaries at all. As soon as those binaries are rebuilt, then you'll lose any changes you make here, if you even manage to achieve your goal. And if the source is not in your control and it has a hardcoded host in there, then tell the devs to fix it.